# Prestashop cash on delivery fee

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am a bit new in prestashop and I have following question.

I am using prestashop 1.6 and I would like to add fee when costumer wants to pay with Cash on delivery. I tried to use some of free modules, but they didn't add fee to final price, so prices listed in back office were without fee.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following paid and free module that will allow you to add charges on ***cash on delivery***
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/75458-module-cash-on-delivery-cod-v05-with-fixed-and-percentage-fees/page-11

https://addons.prestashop.com/en/collect-on-delivery-cod/6337-cash-on-delivery-with-fee-surcharge-plus-cod.html

Comment: thank you very much, that module did work. I am posting link for it here: Link -->https://www.prestashop.com/forums/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_rel_module=post&attach_id=97149

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handling charges on Shipping > Preferences 
Then just enable Handling charges into Cash on delivery settings

[image: Extra fees]

[image: Enable Extra cost]

Comment: But Cash on delivery is payment way, not a carrier.